# Why does promise resolve with promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a promise in my code that consistently fails. When I return a promise to a `Promise#then` callback, rather than wait for the promise to resolve, it passes it as a parameter to the subsequent `Promise#then` call.

See code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Arbolista/52d5a1964414730a4f27) for more detailed code. Calling `House#setEnergyData` would cause the problem (see comments in gist).

The basic pattern that is causing problems in my code looks like this (although this literal code does work):

```
class Class1 {
    step1(){
       return new Promise((fnResolve, fnReject)=>{
       // do something
       fnResolve();
     });
    }

    step2(){
       return this.step1().then(()=>{ 
         // do something else
       });
    }
 }

 class Class2 {

   constructor(){
     this.class1 = new Class1();
   }

   doSomething(){
      this.class1.step2()
        .then((res)=>{
          console.log(res) // Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
          // do something that shouldn't happen until Class1#step2 has finished.
          // error!
        });
   }
 }
```

This is running in a browser and is compiled with Babel ES2015 preset and uses Babel polyfill. I'm not using any `Promise` npm module.

This has recurred in several places in my code. I'm not sure if it's an issue with the compilation process, babel polyfill, or I'm misunderstanding promises.

Comment: @Paulpro I saw that - it was a typo, now fixed.

Comment: show your actual code

Comment: In your sample, you never resolve or reject your promise.

Comment: @naomik The codebase isn't open source, but you can checkout [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Arbolista/52d5a1964414730a4f27) - the problem is when `House#setEnergyData` is called.

Comment: @rgvassar updated, see edit. Also see gist added to question.

Comment: Your code makes no sense - promises never resolve with promises - they always unwrap the value

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that's exactly my response every I get this result - but it certainly happens. See gist if you want to look in more detail.

Comment: So, the only code included in your question is code that does work?  Please include code in your question that does not work - not only something in an external link - those are the stack overflow rules.

Answer (score 1):

Try including `return` statement within `.then()` at `step2` to return value from `Promise` at `step2()` call

```js
class Class1 {
  step1() {
    return new Promise((fnResolve, fnReject) => {
      // do something
      fnResolve(123);
    });
  }
  step2() {
    return this.step1().then((data) => {
      // do something else
      // added `return` here
      return data
    });
  }
}

class Class2 {
  constructor() {
    this.class1 = new Class1();
  }
  doSomething() {
    this.class1.step2()
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res) // 123
      });
  }
}

var c = new Class2();
c.doSomething();
```

Comment: I see that works, but if you look at the gist I provided, that doesn't seem to be a critical difference (I am returning an object in the gist). Also, in `Class1#step2`, try setting an instance variable `this.step2_has_run = true;` and don't return anything. Then in `Class2#doSomething`, `console.log(this.class1.step2_has_run); // true`.

Comment: @EricH. _"I see that works, but if you look at the gist I provided, that doesn't seem to be a critical difference (I am returning an object in the gist). "_ The `javascript` at gist is different from `javascript` at Question ? _"Also, in Class1#step2, try setting an instance variable this.step2_has_run = true; and don't return anything. Then in Class2#doSomething, console.log(this.class1.step2_has_run); // true"_ ? Not certain what expected result is ?

Comment: Yes, the gist is a lot more complicated. In the question I'm just representing the problem in an abstract way... which may not be helpful given that it actually works - and my example in the comment above I was trying to indicate *even without* returning any data, the code still works as expected... I'll make that more clear in the question.

Comment: @EricH. What is expected result ?

Comment: The question is why would a promise ever resolve with another promise as shown in the log statement in the question above.

Comment: `.then()` creates a new `Promise`, though the log message is not indicating that the value of the resolved `Promise` is a `Promise`. The `[[PomiseValue]]` private property is `undefined` at `js` at Question; the resolved value is not a `Promise` . No value was passed to `fnResolve` at `js` at Question. If `123` is passed to `fnResolve` , `123` should be logged at `.then()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106066/discussion-between-eric-h-and-guest271314).